# geom_hline or geom_vline does not seem to accept vector for reference line, if called inside a function and facet_grid() is used

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, custom-function, geom-hline

I have been facing issue with geom_hline or geom_vline if I call it under custom function and it takes the value from a vector. It seems to work fine until I add facet_grid() within that function body.e.g
**Without Function**

```
c<- data.frame(A = c("carr","bike","truck","carr","truck","bike","bike","carr","truck","carr","truck","truck","carr","truck","truck"),
                B = c(10,20,30,23,45,56,78,44,10,20,30,10,20,30,67),
                D = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,2,3,2,1))
a = c(1:4)*4
ggplot(c, aes(A,B, color = D))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid( .~D)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = a,linetype = "dotted",size =0.3)
```

`

I get this: [image]

But **With Function**

```
    tk_fun <- function(dat,x1,y1,clr){   # I need to have this a declared and defined with in function.  
 a = c(1:4)*4.5  p <- ggplot(dat, aes_string(colnames(dat)[1],colnames(dat)[2], color = colnames(dat)[3]))+
    geom_point()+    facet_grid( .~dat[,3])+
    geom_hline(yintercept = a,linetype = "dotted",size =0.3)  return(p) } tk_fun(c,"A","B","D")
```

With function I am getting this error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L,  : 
>     replacement has 15 rows, data has 4
>   I hope someone can help me in figuring out, how to do it through function, without an error. Thanks

Comment: don't assign an object with name `c`. `c` is an essential base function that you use in your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your definition of the facets. You need to create an appropriate formula call with the correct variable name, not use the data directly. Using `paste` and `as.formula` can help here.

```
tk_fun <- function(dat,x1,y1,clr){   # I need to have this a declared and defined with in function.  
  a = c(1:4)*4.5  
  p <- ggplot(dat, aes_string(colnames(dat)[1],colnames(dat)[2], color = colnames(dat)[3]))+
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(as.formula(paste('. ~', names(dat)[3]))) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = a, linetype = "dotted", size =0.3)  
  return(p) 
}
```